# File of a module importing another file

Tags: python, import, module

I have some problem importing a class from a module when I run test_or.py:

```
.
├── mymodule
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── neuron.py
│   └── perceptron.py
└── test_or.py
```

Every file has these import statements:

**test_or.py** `from mymodule.perceptron import Perceptron`

**perceptron.py** `from neuron import Neuron`

**neuron.py** imports only standard from modules

**__init__.py** is empty

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_or.py", line 1, in <module>
    from mymodule.perceptron import Perceptron
  File "/home/andrea/ann/mymodule/perceptron.py", line 1, in <module>
    from neuron import Neuron
ImportError: No module named 'neuron'
```

If I run `perceptron.py` from the folder where there is `neuron.py` it works correctly but if I run it from the "main" folder Python tells me the same error.

I think I don't know how a module have to be organized.

Comment: Are you sure `test_or.py` has that import statement? 'Cause the error message doesn't match what you wrote

Comment: Ops, you're right, I corrected

Comment: You have a capital `N`, is the file called neuron.py or Neuron.py?

Comment: Ops again, I corrected the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your current working directory is relative to `test_or.py`. Change the line in `perceptron.py` to:

```
from mymodule.neuron import Neuron
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! However I don't understand why, if perceptron.py and neuron.py are both in the same module (and in the same folder) why I must specify the name of the module?

Comment: Because you're importing based on your current working directory. If you start from `test_or.py`, that is `./` (the directory you start it from), even though `perceptron.py` is in `./mymodule/`